# Why can't touchDown and mouseDown be combined?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, mobile, standards, w3c

So in Actionscript 3 and Javascript, to get touch events working for mobile devices I have to listen for ontouch events... However, touch events not fired on desktop.
However, mouse events are triggered on both mobile AND desktop.

My quesion is this: why does w3 have this spec

Wouldn't it make sense to have just to use the onmouseevent? In order to have things work on mobile and desktop I always have to listen for both events - obviously this causes issue on mobile devices because two events are fired when i press the screen (meaning that I have to do a bunch of conditional checking to add/remove event)

My initial thoughts were that multi-touch would be the main reason... But couldn't the design just have some parameter of the event like .touches? That could go along with the .pressure, .finger width, etc... maybe a .type = "touch" or .type="mouse"

I'm sure a lot of thought went into having touch events, so I'd bet there are some valid reasons.

Comment: Check out flash.ui.Multitouch class , there is value Multitouch.mapTouchToMouse value that may help You . http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/Multitouch.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The W3C has published an [initial draft of a specification that combines mouse and touch events into a single family of Pointer Events](http://www.w3.org/Submission/2012/SUBM-pointer-events-20120907/).

Windows 8 and IE10 currently ship with support for this unified event style.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with ECMA. This touch event/mouse event interaction is covered by [this spec section](http://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/#mouse-events). In particular, a note in green says,

> "If a Web application can process touch events, it can intercept them,
>   and no corresponding mouse events would need to be dispatched by the
>   user agent. If the Web application is not specifically written for
>   touch input devices, it can react to the subsequent mouse events
>   instead."

I suggest that you get familiar with the referenced specification.

Comment: Nice. Didn't know there was such a document. I wonder if preventDefault will stop mouse event in flash too. Though I heard that sometimes in as3 on devices mouse event is dispatched BEFORE touch event.

Comment: Yes, everything that is not covered by the JS spec should be covered by some other spec - in most cases it will be a w3c spec, so you can google related topics using the `some topic site:w3.org` search engine query.

Comment: thanks @AlexanderPavlov , but my original question is WHY is it designed like that?

Comment: @K2xL The mouse event APIs (specifically, the `MouseEvent` interface) appeared about a decade earlier than the touch screens were considered for DOM event generation ([this doc](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html) dates back to November, 2000). I guess, that's the main reason.